# How to properly post back information about a checkbox onclick event (RoR3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting starting with RoR and this is my first attempt to use the new remote_function. I have sort of a project management app so you have projects (streams) and they have multiple tasks. Inside the stream show view, I want to list out the tasks with a checkbox next to them. If a user clicks on the checkbox, I want to post to /tasks/3 sending done=true so that the record will be probably updated.

Here is code I came up with:

<%= check_box_tag "id", "id", task.done, 
    :onclick => remote_function(
      :update => "task", 
      :url => { :action => :update }, 
      :with => "'done=true'", 
      :complete => "alert('hi')"  ) %>

It does print the checkbox, and it does check it automatically depending on the status of task.done. But when I fire the onclick and watch the logs, I see the following entry:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/streams/3"):

"/streams/3" doesn't sound right, I would really be expecting to see something like /tasks/id instead.

Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Here is the full code for the view.

```
<tr>
  <td class="task">
    <span class="tasktitle">


<%= check_box_tag "id", "id", task.done, 
    :onclick => remote_function(
      :update => "task", 
      :url => { :action => :update }, 
      :with => "'done=true'", 
      :complete => "alert('hi')"  ) %>



<span class="<%= if (task.done) then "editable_field_complete" else "editable_field" end %>" id="task_title_<%= task.id %>">
<%= best_in_place task, :title, :type => :input %>
</span>
</span>
    <span class="taskdelete"><%= link_to "delete", task, :method => :delete, :class => "delete",
                                     :confirm => "You sure?",
                                     :title => task.title %></span>
    <span class="taskcreated">
      Created <%= time_ago_in_words(task.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

Is the checkbox within a 'stream' view?

Simply write    `:url => { :action => :update, :controller => 'tasks'}`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: I added the controller property and also an ID property with the taskId and I see now that it is posting to the right place, but when I look at the logs, I still see this error message: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/tasks/20"): I checked my config/routes file and I see that I have properly defined resources :tasks. What else can I be missing?

Comment: could you please add your routes.rb to your post? and can you access /tasks/20 with your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Error reason: 
Forgot to mention controller pointer
Suggestoin: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html 
Always Refer [api for rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org) its quite helpful for me.

Comment: I added the controller property and also an ID property with the taskId and I see now that it is posting to the right place, but when I look at the logs, I still see this error message: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/tasks/20"):
I checked my config/routes file and I see that I have properly defined *resources :tasks*. What else can I be missing?